# ' Error Code: E_FAIL ' when creating DirectX 10 Device and Swap Chain

Tags: c++, directx

I am working though some simple DX tutorials of the book 'Introduction to 3D Game Programming with Direct3D 10.0'.  I encountered some problems  when I use the function of D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain.  The following is the code：

```
        // Fill out a DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC to describe our swap chain.

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;


    sd.BufferDesc.Width  = mClientWidth;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = mClientHeight;

    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;

    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    sd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    // No multisampling.
    sd.SampleDesc.Count   = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    sd.BufferUsage  = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.BufferCount  = 1;
    sd.OutputWindow = mhMainWnd;
    sd.Windowed     = true;
    sd.SwapEffect   = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    sd.Flags        = 0;


    // Create the device.

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;

#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)  
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    HR( D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
            0,                 //default adapter

            md3dDriverType,
            //D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,

            0,                 // no software device
            createDeviceFlags, 

            D3D10_SDK_VERSION,
            &sd,
            &mSwapChain,
            &md3dDevice) );
```

And the error information is that:

Error Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Calling:D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(.....

when I change the parameter 'createDeviceFlags' of D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain  to  0 , then  It works.  But why??  I  want to know the reason, who can tell me ???

Answer (score 2):

MSDN Says

> To create a device that supports the debug layer, you must install the DirectX SDK (to get D3D10SDKLayers.DLL), and then specify the D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag when calling D3D10CreateDevice.

So, did you install the SDK and do you have D3D10SDKLayers.DLL?

Comment: I install the SDK of Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)  There have D3D10SDKLayers.DLL in C:\Windows\System32

Comment: It may be a bad install of the SDK - some mismatched components perhaps - can you try to completely uninstall and reinstall the SDK and see what happens? Also, if using Visual Studio, make sure you have the DX includes and libs in the correct place in VC++ directories - should come after the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this exact problem. I got it to work when I switched out the D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag for 0. I think my computer is having trouble creating the debug layer for some reason. Not sure why, but at least I was able to create a window that way.

Comment: Seems like an update somewhere has actually broken this debug mode in some older hardware, judging by comments and posts throughout the internet. Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue with VS2010 on Windows 8 with DirectX SDK June 2010.

If I disable the debug layer everything works fine. This is of course rather annoying because the debug layer of DirectX is rather handy.

I also tried this workaround for a succesful installation of the DirectX SDK, but it didn't help me:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/12/09/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error.aspx

Is there already a solution for this?